# Prevent text jumping up the screen when dismissing Swiper

Tags: window, minibuffer, window-splitting, swiper

[Swiper](https://github.com/abo-abo/swiper#swiper) creates a minibuffer many lines in height.  This height is borrowed equally from my existing, vertically-arranged, windows.  When Swiper is dismissed, this space is recovered by the windows and they all grow slightly, moving down the screen as they do so.

The consequence of this is that the text that I've just searched for jumps down the screen.  I find this jarring, and would like to prevent it from happening.  Any ideas?

The documentation suggests that setting [window-combination-resize](https://www.gnu.org/software/emacs/manual/html_node/elisp/Recombining-Windows.html#index-window_002dcombination_002dresize) to `nil` should do what I want, but this is already set to `nil`; it seems that either this doesn't apply to minibuffers, or something is preventing it from taking effect in this case.

Comment: I don't know how to stop the line that you've just searched for moving, but you might find that using global-hl-line-mode helps you not lose track of line as it moves.